# AWS Cloudformation: How to split a string on 'NewLine' character

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a set of strings in Cloudformation, this is how they appear on the command line:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app0/yyy
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app4/yyy
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app1/yyy
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app2/yyy
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app3/yyy
```

I need to split on '\n' (the new line character)

The strings were generated by CF's CommandRunner:

```
  GetElbv2Arns:
    Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner
    Properties: 
      Role: InfrastructureManagement
      LogGroup: !Ref LogGroup
      SubnetId: !Ref subnetId1
      Command: 
        !Sub 
          - | 
            aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers \
            --region ${AWS::Region} \
            --query "LoadBalancers[].[LoadBalancerArn]" \
            --output text  \
            > /command-output.txt
          - dummy: ""
```

Comment: Are those strings in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that event though the value started with '\n' as new line, it is actually just '\n' as text by the time CF gets the value. This is what is displayed in CF's Output pane:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app0/yyy\narn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app4/yyy\narn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app1/yyy\narn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app2/yyy\narn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxx:loadbalancer/app/app3/yyy
```

The way to parse the values is to escape the '\':

```
Outputs:
  ARNs1:
    Description: "elbv2 Arns-0"
    Value: 
       !Select [0, !Split  [ "\\n", !GetAtt GetElbv2Arns.Output] ]
```